# Add "No results found" message on div search

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an audio player, and I have a list of divs acting as my playlist... I'm using JS to make the list, and I'm using this script to search through them:

```
/*Search Songs*/
function searchSongs(){
  let input = _('#songSearch').value.toLowerCase();
  let items = _all('.item');
  let dividers = _all(".divider");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (!items[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      items[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      items[i].style.display = "";
    }
  }
  
  // add noresults message at end if all list divs are hidden
  if (!items.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
    _('.noResults').innerHTML = `<p>No results found for "${input}"`
  }
}
```

I have a paragraph element at the end of my list (with nothing in it) and I want to show the message (`<p>No results found for "${input}"`) is there some js I can use to accomplish this? The script above is working for the searching, but not working for the message.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to *why* the code you've provided here doesn't meet your requirements? "*The script above is... not working for the message.*" isn't descriptive enough to understand where the actual behavior of this code deviates from your expectation. It's also worth pointing out the `<p>` you open in your setting of the `innerHTML` property is not closed, which can lead to some oddities in the markup that ends up being displayed.

Comment: You can create a flag counter in FOR LOOP and then use it in IF condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finished result:

```
/*Search Songs*/
function searchSongs(){
  let input = _('#songSearch').value.toLowerCase();
  let items = _all('.item');
  let dividers = _all(".divider");
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (!items[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      items[i].style.display = "none";
      counter++;
    }
    else {
      items[i].style.display = "";
    }
  }
  
  // keeping the result 22 letters long (for asthetic purposes)
  let maxLen = 22;
  if (input.length > maxLen) {
    input = input.substring(0, maxLen - 3) + "...";
  }
  
  if (counter >= items.length) {
    _('#noResults').innerHTML = `No results found for "${input}"` //add no results message if all items are hidden...
  } else {
    _('#noResults').innerHTML = `` //else hide the message by removing text.
  }
}
```

Thanks, @Asif !!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little modification in your function. I hope this will solve your issue.

```
/*Search Songs*/
function searchSongs(){
  let input = _('#songSearch').value.toLowerCase();
  let items = _all('.item');
  let dividers = _all(".divider");
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (!items[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      items[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      items[i].style.display = "";
      counter++;
    }
  }
  
  // add noresults message at end if all list divs are hidden
  if (counter > 0) {
    _('.noResults').innerHTML = `<p>No results found for "${input}"`
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think of using a counter... This works perfectly, just had to move where `counter++` was and make it `counter >= 0`!

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as useful, So, It would help others too.

Comment: Also, make an edit if you like to correct the answer.